# RegionPlot of a ParametricRegion (problems MMA v11.0.1)

Tags: regions

Having problems to visualize a ParametricRegion I took an example from the documentation

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] =ParametricRegion[{{s, (1 + t) s^2 - t}, -1 <= s <= 1 && 
 0 <= t <= 1}, {s, t}];
DiscretizeRegion[\[ScriptCapitalR], {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

which works a s described.

But  RegionPlot

```
RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

shows only a triangle?

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Following your code using version 12, I see what you would expect (just the filled outline of the shape of your first figure). What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: My version is 11.0.1.  Does MMA 12 show the expected plot?

Comment: Works fine on V12. Have you tried increasing `PlotPoints`?

Comment: @Roman I tried `Plotpoints` but it doesn't help. It seems to be v11.0.1 problem?